# sending Power BI report via email to internal teams (Distribution group)

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I want to share the power BI report to the people who are not pro licensed users in our organization. Is there any way to do it as i could only add the people who have pro license as of now. As I want to share the reports on weekly basis to the internal larger group in the organization, I couldn't make all of them get the pro license. I am not looking for PDF versions. Also, Is there a way to send this using custom mail box rather than from the Microsoft Power BI email (i.e. the email of the report should go from my email id rather than the default microsoft power bi email id).

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of options but I suspect none meet your needs.

1) Install Power BI Desktop on all user's PCs and have them manually open the file from a network share.

2) Make the report accessible to the public, then everyone can access it for free (and I mean everyone).

3) Power BI Premium allows access without a Pro licence but it's significantly more expensive and only makes economic sense if you're talking about needing over 600 users.

4) If you have an SQL Server Enterprise agreement and Software Assurance then you can install Power BI Report Server locally. It largely does the same things but is a bit behind the cloud version.